# find the set $α$ that $B_α is$ postive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

For each real number α, let $B_α$ be the bilinear form
$B_α((x_1, y_1, z_1),(x_2, y_2, z_2))
=x_1x_2 + 2y_1y_2 + 11z_1z_2 + (α + 1)(x_1y_2 + y_1x_2) + 3(x_1z_2 + z_1x_2) + (α + 2)(y_1z_2 + z_1y_2).$

Find the set {$α ∈ R : B_α$ is positive definite}

My attempts :  i  was reading this  articles..but  couldnot get  any hints  to tackle this  question.......

http://www.imsc.res.in/~knr/ece15/ps.pdf

my thinking :  i take  $x_1= x_2 , y_1= y_2, z_1 =z_3$...after  that  i  make
 $B_α((x_1, y_1, z_1),(x_1, y_1, z_1)=x_1x_1 + 2y_1y_1 + 11z_1z_1 + (α + 1)(x_1y_1 + y_1x_1) + 3(x_1z_1 + z_1x_1) + (α + 2)(y_1z_1 + z_1y_1).$
 $B_α((x_1, y_1, z_1),(x_1, y_1, z_1)=x_1^2 + 2y_1^2 + 11z_1^2+ (α + 1)(2x_1y_1 ) + 3(2x_1z_1 ) + (α + 2)(2y_1z_1 ).$

Now  converting them  into  matrix

$$B_α =\begin{bmatrix} 1& α+1 &3 \\  α+ 1 &2 &  α+2\\ 3& α +2 & 11\end{bmatrix} >0$$

For  positive  definite  $Det B > 0$

= $-α^2 - 2α + 7 -8(α^2 + 13α + 5) +3α^2 + 3α -12  > 0 $

=$-6α^2 -12α > 0$

=  $α > - \frac {12}{6}$

=$α > - 2$

Is  my answer  is  correct   ? or not  correct ???

Pliz  verified  my answer

Comment: Observe that the second first minor, namely $2-(\alpha+1)^2$ might be negative.

Comment: what  will be the answer??@MichaelHoppe

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion, please.